# plantuml inner group exceeded the outer group

Tags: plantuml

How to make the second ref fragment `SecondaryErrorHandling(CommunicationError)` within the alt fragment?

[image]

```
@startuml
hide footbox
hide unlinked

i2c -> app ++ : I2C request completed
app -> i2c : getI2CStatus(&result)

alt result == OK
  ref over app, app : I2CJobEndProcessing()
else
  ref over app, app  : SecondaryErrorHandling(CommunicationError)
end

@enduml
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. You could report it on the forum.plantuml.com

One solution is to use `\n` to force your text in the ref to wrap:

```
@startuml
hide footbox
hide unlinked

i2c -> app ++ : I2C request completed
app -> i2c : getI2CStatus(&result)

alt result == OK
  ref over app, app : I2CJobEndProcessing()
else
  ref over app, app  : SecondaryErrorHandling(\nCommunicationError)
end

@enduml
```

[image: Plantuml image]